# Use dynamically created html content later with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic-content

I have a method where I dynamically create a table and assign it to a local variable:

```
 var content = $('<table id="gvCapitalByYear" cellspacing="0"
       cellpadding="2"/>').append('<tbody/>');
```

Then I have a loop that is meant to add rows to the above created table. But I can't anyhow get this done. I tried the following:

```
content=$('#gvCapitalByYear').find('tbody').append('<tr/>');
```

but it doesn't work, as, in my opinion, an element with id "gvCapitalByYear" has not been appended to anywhere, it was just created on the fly and kept in a variable. Is it possible to  somehow use the content variable get the dynamically created table, add certain amount of  rows to and the reassign it back to the content variable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `content` variable instead of querying the DOM for these elements (e.g., `$('#gvCapitalByYear')`) because the content hasn't been attached to the DOM yet.

Once you wrap the table HTML as a jQuery object, you can query and manipulate it just like any other jQuery object. The object is "live" so you won't need to reassign the `content` variable once you append more content.

```
var content = $('<table id="gvCapitalByYear" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><tbody></tbody></table>');
//later, add as many rows as you like
content.find('tbody').append('<tr><td>Some Content Here</td></tr>');
```

Also, `table`, `tbody` and `tr` elements aren't self-closing tags, you will need to have an opening tag and closing tag for each for this to be valid HTML.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dCmF3/2)**

Comment: Yeah, I know that I have to add it to the DOM but I don't want to. Instead, I would like to use the content variable that keeps the html content created earlier.

Comment: That would be all right if I knew how many rows I have to add, but the count of rows to be added to the table is variable. That's y, I first create the table, then I go into a loop that iterates through an array and adds as many rows as the count of the array.

Comment: This would work just fine for that case; I updated the demo showing how to add 10 rows dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body').append('<table id="gvCapitalByYear" cellspacing="0"
   cellpadding="2"></table>');
```

then

```
$('#gvCapitalByYear').append('<tr><td>my data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Again, I know that to later reference the "gvCapitalByYear" I need to append it to the body, or at least to some container that is in the same content but that's why I need a way to use the local content variable to extract the html content.